# NSXMLParser and Swift

Tags: swift

I have found several examples of using NSXMLParser in Swift on the web and on this board that look like this:

```
var parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)
parser.delegate = self
parser.parse ()
```

Went I try that code, I get errors. Xcode suggests changing to

```
var parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)
parser?.delegate = self
parser?.parse ()
```

Why am I not being able to use these examples?

Another issue I am finding is the return value.

```
parser?.parse ()
```

does not seem to return a Bool value.

What should I be doing to parse and get the return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is merely that the Swift language and the Cocoa APIs (as translated into Swift) are changing very rapidly. When those examples were written, NSXMLParser's `init(contentsOfURL:)` did not return an Optional. But now it does, so you must adjust accordingly.

Comment: Your question seems to imply that you don't even know what an Optional _is_. That's bad - it is impossible to use Swift without _knowing_ Swift, and Optionals are essential. Here's my new tutorial explanation: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_optional

Comment: I think the question more reflects I am reading the documentation. The Swift guide (P.24) says that you "can" put a "?" after the optional. and suggests that the "?" does a null check and omitting it does not. In addition the, the NSXMLParser class reference says parse() returns a bool value while it appears not to do so.

Comment: `parse()` does return a Bool. But messaging an optionally unwrapped Optional wraps the result in an Optional, so what you are getting is an Optional wrapping the Bool. This is why I suggested you read my tutorial; it explains this.